# Change the coordinates on a tiles map

Tags: openlayers

I've a map created with tiles and a tilegrid with this properties:

```
extent: [-512000, -512000, 512000, 512000],
resolutions: [512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1],
tileSize: [256, 256]
```

and this code:

```
let view = new View({
    extent: mapConfig.extent,
    center: [0, 0],
    constrainResolution: true,
    zoom: currentZoom,
    resolutions: [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125]
});

let tileImage = new Tile({
    interpolate: false,
    url: '/map_data/world/{z}/{x}_{y}.png',
    wrapX: false,
    crossOrigin: null,
    tileGrid: new TileGrid({
        extent: mapConfig.extent,
        resolutions: mapConfig.resolutions,
        tileSize: mapConfig.tileSize
    })
});

let mapLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: tileImage,
    extent: mapConfig.extent
});

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [mapLayer],
    view: view
});
```

The problem is that I want coordinates to go from -512000 at the top("north pole") to 512000("south pole")... but it's the opposite, is going from 512000 at the top to -512000 at the bottom.
Left to right works fine, - to the left and + to the right.

How can I change coordinates to go from - north to + south?

Idk what to try, is not explained on the poor docs